# No Data In Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

I am creating an app which uses Core Data. I have a flip-side in which the user creates the records which are to be used in the main-view. I fetch the Core Data in my ViewWillAppear in the MainViewController. The problem arises when I run the app on a new device, it returns the error that there is no data in the array.

I populate the array as follows:

```
/*
 Fetch existing events.
 Create a fetch request; find the Event entity and assign it to the request; add a sort descriptor; then execute the fetch.
 */
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Child" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

// Order the events by creation date, most recent first.
NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *prizeDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"prize" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *neededDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"marblesneeded" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *colorDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"color" ascending:NO];



NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:nameDescriptor,prizeDescriptor,neededDescriptor,colorDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[nameDescriptor release];
[colorDescriptor release];
[prizeDescriptor release];
[neededDescriptor release];
[sortDescriptors release];

// Execute the fetch -- create a copy of the result.
NSError *error = nil;
records = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] retain];

if ([records count] == 0) {
    recordsempty = YES;
}

[request release];
```

And I get the following error:

```
-[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Does anyone have any ideas on helping prevent this crash when a user installs my app from the App Store?

Thanks

Comment: it would be helpful if you gave details about the crash as well as some code that shows how you are putting objects into the array.

Comment: @timthetoolman, I have added the code and the errors.

Comment: You should indicate where in the code you are getting the error.  If you only get the error when there's no data, then somewhere you have some code that expects there to be data at index:0.

Comment: @OwenHartnett, Yes, if The User has not entered any data, the fetch will not return any data causing the error.

Comment: Yes, but where does the error happen in your code? Somewhere your code is acting like there is data there and is trying to get index:0 and it isn't there.

Comment: @OwenHartnett, The Default for pageControl.CurrentPage is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was fixed after I added an if statement to not try to display anything if the array is empty. Then, I used an UIAlertView to direct the user to the flipside.